# How to add bindings for WindowsFormHost hosted ReportViewer control

Tags: wpf, binding, reportviewer

I'm using Microsoft's `ReportViewer` control in my WPF application. Since this is a WinForms component, I use the WindowsFormHost control.

I try to follow the MVVM pattern as supported by the [WPF Application Framework](http://waf.codeplex.com), so I implemented a `ReportViewModel` which contains (amongst others) the current report name and the dataset (both can be selected by 'regular' WPF controls, that part works fine).

I'd like to be as "WPF-ish" as possible, so how would I properly set up the binding to the ReportViewer component (which is inside the WindowsFormHost control)? I need to set the `ReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource` property and have a call to `ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add` (and possibly `Clear`) whenever the view models report name or dataset change. What's the proper way to do that?

Is there any chance to use one of the regular WPF binding mechanisms for that? If yes, how? If no, how would I set up the binding? (its my first 'real' WPF project, so don't be shy to post trivial solutions :) ...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So far I've come up with the following solution (purly code-behind):

```
private void MyDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
  if (e.OldValue is ReportViewModel) {
    var viewModel = e.OldValue as ReportViewModel;
    viewModel.PropertyChanged -= ViewModelPropertyChanged;
  }
  if (DataContext is ReportViewModel) {
    var viewModel = DataContext as ReportViewModel;
    viewModel.PropertyChanged += ViewModelPropertyChanged;
    SetReportData();
  }
}

void ViewModelPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
  if (e.PropertyName == "ReportName" || e.PropertyName == "ReportData") 
    SetReportData();
}

private void SetReportData() {
  var viewModel = DataContext as ReportViewModel;
  if (viewModel != null) {
    var reportView = reportHost.Child as ReportViewer;
    reportView.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = viewModel.ReportName;
    reportView.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    reportView.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", viewModel.ReportData as DataTable));
    reportView.RefreshReport();
  }
}
```

I'm still curious if there are any better solutions (I'm sure there are ...).